# django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: docker, postgresql, python, django, docker-compose

I found a Django project and failed to get it running in Docker container in the following way:

1. `git clone https://github.com/hotdogee/django-blast.git`
2. `$ cat requirements.txt` in this files the below dependencies had to be updated:

   - kombu==3.0.30
   - psycopg2==2.8.6

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

For `docker-compose.yml` I use:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Next, I ran into this error:

```
$ docker-compose build
...

web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  | Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f265ed26850>
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 223, in wrapper
web_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
web_1  |     self.check_migrations()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 164, in check_migrations
web_1  |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
web_1  |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
web_1  |     self.build_graph()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 180, in build_graph
web_1  |     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
web_1  |     self.ensure_schema()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
web_1  |     if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 162, in cursor
web_1  |     cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
web_1  |     self.ensure_connection()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
web_1  |     six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
web_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 172, in get_new_connection
web_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
web_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1  |    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
web_1  |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, the communication with postgres is hardcoded in the app in a way that app assumes the db is on the same host (non-prod: [127.0.0.1](https://github.com/hotdogee/django-blast/blob/afce3da522c798318f3f737880c467c7b6f2f986/i5k/settings.py#L56) and prod: [127.0.0.1](https://github.com/hotdogee/django-blast/blob/afce3da522c798318f3f737880c467c7b6f2f986/i5k/settings_prod.py#L24))

thus the error:

```
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: You are right. I think I have to change all the below addresses. Which address docker-compose is using? ```
axes/tests.py: reset(ip='127.0.0.1')
axes/decorators.py: ip_address = '127.0.0.1'
index.html: fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
index.html: fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
data/db/pg_hba.conf:host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
data/db/pg_hba.conf:host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
i5k/settings_prod.py: 'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
i5k/settings.py: 'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
i5k/settings.py: 'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable listen addresses if you are using remote database.

```
cd /etc/postgresql/12.x/main/
```

open file named postgresql.conf

```
sudo nano postgresql.conf
```

add this line to that file

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

then an open a file named pg_hba.conf

```
sudo nano pg_hba.conf
```

and add this line to that file

```
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

restart your server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```